# How can I locate a lost home/base in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I took two days to build this resort, underground. It was just me and my tamed wolf in the entire place. I hadn’t set my spawn point (which was stupid) and it is an infinite world.

Now, I log off to eat and when I log back in, I’m at my first spawn point. So I lost my house and my dog. Is there a cheat or something where I can spawn to the location of my pet? Just anything where I can get back home.

Answer (score 1):

If you renamed your dog, you can run this command (turn cheats on):

```
/tp @s @e[type=wolf,name=YourDogName,c=1]
```

This will teleport yourself to the nearest wolf with the name YourDogName.

However, if your dog's name has spaces or symbols or if you didn't name it at all, you can try executing this command:

```
/tp @s @e[type=wolf,c=1]
```

If the wolf you get teleported to isn't yours, you can kill it and run the command again.